# powershell command result writing extra lines of space

Tags: powershell, lines, extra, get-wmiobject

I don't know why these commands resulting in extra lines, looks like 2 or 3 lines after the OS caption. How do I rid of the lines after the OS caption?

```
cls
(Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName server1).Caption
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName server1 | Select-Object -Property BuildNumber,BuildType,OSType,ServicePackMajorVersion,ServicePackMinorVersion
```

Result output:

Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

BuildNumber             : 9600
BuildType               : Multiprocessor Free
OSType                  : 18
ServicePackMajorVersion : 0
ServicePackMinorVersion : 0

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to fetch OS info just use the below

```
Function OSCheck() {
SystemInfo | Select-String '^OS '
[System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version
}

Echo "Operating System "
Echo "-------------------------------"
OSCheck
```

Output

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Member Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
```

Comment: Thanks.This is really good, but how can I utilize it with different computer names since I want to check multiple machines?

Comment: On the computer you want to run remote script
1. Open PS and admin
2. Enable-PSRemoting -Force
3. On both computers, configure the TrustedHosts setting so the computers will trust each other
4. Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts *
5. Restart-Service WinRM
6. Test the connection Test-WsMan <remote computer name>

Execute

Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTER -ScriptBlock { COMMAND } -credential USERNAME